# How to persist items position in firestore after vertically drag & drop them on a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I try to persist the position of items of a todo list app after I vertically draged & droped the todo items. I use a RecyclerView/FirestoreRecylerAdapter/ItemTouchHelper/Firestore. In the onMove()-Method of the ItemTouchHelper.Callback I access Firestore I guess with asyncronious calls. This leads to unwanted content changes in my RecyclerView. Imagine I have a list of 4 items with Titles A, B, C, D. Now I drag the Item with title A from position 0 (at the top) to position 1. Like this item B's title also changes to A. But this is only on the UI and not in the DB. When I change to another activity and come back then the titles are correct again. I guess it has todo with the asyncronious calls.

```
//part of MainActivity onCreate()
mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    FirebaseFirestore.setLoggingEnabled(true);

    FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
            .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
            .build();
    mFirestore.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if(mUser == null){
        startSignIn();
    }else{
        Query mQuery = mFirestore.collection("todos").whereEqualTo("author", mUser.getUid()).whereEqualTo("done", false).orderBy("position", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Todo> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Todo>()
                .setQuery(mQuery, Todo.class)
                .build();
        mAdapter = new TodoAdapter(options);

        initRecyclerView();

//ItemTouchHelper.Callback method as part of initRecyclerView()
@Override
        public boolean onMove(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final RecyclerView.ViewHolder source, final RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            if (source.getItemViewType() != target.getItemViewType()) {
                return false;
            }

            int fromPos = source.getAdapterPosition();
            int toPos = target.getAdapterPosition();

            //Change items position when an item was draged & droped vertically downwards
            if(toPos > fromPos) {
                DocumentReference docTo = mAdapter.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(fromPos).getReference();
                docTo.update("position", toPos);
                int current = fromPos+1;
                while(current <= toPos){
                    DocumentReference docCurrent = mAdapter.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(current).getReference();
                    docCurrent.update("position", current-1);
                    current ++;
                }

                //Change items position when an item was draged & droped vertically upwards
            }else if (toPos < fromPos){
                //TODO implement
            } else {
                return false;
            }

            mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPos, toPos);

            return true;
        }

//adapter class
public class TodoAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Todo, TodoAdapter.TodoHolder> {

private static final String TAG = "DOIT_DEBUG: ";

private OnItemClickListener listener;
private View viewItem;

public TodoAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Todo> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TodoHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Todo model) {
    holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
    holder.textViewDescription.setText(model.getDescription());
}

@NonNull
@Override
public TodoHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    viewItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_todo,
            parent, false);
    return new TodoHolder(viewItem);
}

public void deleteItem(final int position) {
    getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
}

public void setDoneItem(int position){
    getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().update("done", true);
    viewItem.setEnabled(false);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
}

public class TodoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView textViewTitle;
    private TextView textViewDescription;
    private String documentID;

    public TodoHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todo_title);
        textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todo_description);


        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null){
                    listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}


//model class
public class Todo {

private String title;
private String description;
private String author;
private boolean done;
private int position;
private Date created;

public Todo(){} // Needed for Firebase

public Todo(String title, String description, String author, boolean done, int position, Date created) {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.author = author;
    this.done = done;
    this.position = position;
    this.created = created;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public boolean getDone() {
    return done;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public void setDone(boolean done) {
    this.done = done;
}

public int getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(int position) {
    this.position = position;
}

@ServerTimestamp
public Date getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(Date created) {
    this.created = created;
}
```

//DB structure

Collection "todos"
Document fields: author string, created timestamp, description string, done boolean, position number, title string

I expect the drag & drop position change to be persistet in Firestore and that the RecyclerView only displays the correct move of the items and no other changes.

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to achieve this was by storing the position and updating it when necessary. If you give each item a ranking, you just need to write to an item when the item is affected.

I just have a reorder function that writes the new ranking each time the item is moved, if I move item 15 to position 1, I need to change all positions of 1-15. Depending on the frequency of the functionality, you can get clever like storing the ranking and only updating it after a few seconds of no other change (to avoid a user making 50 changes very quickly and updating each time).

It's not optimal, but persisting via the database seems to require a dedicated field and therefore this approach.

Comment: Do you mean, that I need to write the new item positions in my above onMove() method first e.g. in an array and then persist it after some time in another Java thread in Firestore? How could an example code look like?

Comment: But what if I immediatly after drag & drop want to persist the new positions in Firestore? This is actualy my requirement. But this doesn't work with above onMove() code properly. So how do I need to change the methods code?